# setState on submit and not onChange

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I have a form, where I use the input from the input fields to send to a back-end.

For example, I have a variable looking something like this:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])
const [inputField, setInputField] = useState()
```

Then I have a `form` that looks something like this:

```
<form onSubmit={fetchData}>
    <input type="number" value={value} onChange={(e) => setInputField(e.target.value)} />
    <button type="submit">Fetch data</button>
</form>
```

The `fetchData` is given by:

```
function fetchData(e?: any) {
    e?.preventDefault();
    POST("/api", {
      inputField: inputField,
    }).then(async (response) => {
      const json = await response.json();
      setData({
        retrievedData: json.retrievedData,
      });
    });
  }
```

I have other forms as well, where this `onChange` updating is good, but for some input fields I don't need it do update/re-render before the actual submit button that triggers the form are clicked.

So how do I update the state of the `inputField` when the button is clicked, instead of now where it updates every time I write a new character in the input field ?

Comment: You can make use of refs in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
import {useRef } from "react";

export const Temp = () => {
  const inputField = useRef(null);

  const onBtnClick = () => {
    alert(inputField?.current?.value);
  };
  return (
    <div>

        <input type="text" ref={inputField} />
        <button type="submit" onClick={onBtnClick}>
          Fetch data
        </button>
      </div>

  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useRef` hook for that.

```
const inputNumber = useRef();

<input
   ref={inputNumber}
   id="number"
   placeholder="33xx"
   type="number"
 />
```

Then on button click you can get the value like that

```
inputNumber.current?.value,
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a state for that and you don't even need a ref. You can get the form values directly from the submit event (`event.target.<input name>.value`). You will need to add the `name` property to the `<input />` to make it accessible from the event target. Please, find the example below:

```js
function Form() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState();

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const inputField = e.target.inputField.value;
    POST("/api", {
      inputField: inputField,
    }).then(async (response) => {
      const json = await response.json();
      setData({
        retrievedData: json.retrievedData,
      });
    });
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <input type="text" name="inputField" />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Form />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```